# Function that is $o(x)$ but not $O(x^2)$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Maybe I might be not very precise in the definition but I think

> $f(x) \in O(x)$ means $\exists C$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert \le
> C\lvert x\rvert$
>
> $f(x) \in o(x)$ means $\forall C \exists \delta$ such that $x\in
> (-\delta,\delta) \implies \lvert f(x)\rvert \le C\lvert x\rvert$.

It seems that $f\in O(x^2) \implies f\in o(x)$ but I think the converse might not be true. I was wondering if there were an easy example of a function with $f\in o(x)$ but $f\not\in O(x^2)$

Comment: Maybe try a power of 1.5

Comment: @CalvinKhor, nice thank you

Comment: $f(x)\in o(x)\implies f(x)\in O(x)\implies f(x)\in O(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be precise when you write $o(x)$ or $O(x)$ because it supposes you have a point of reference.

- The definition of $f(x) \underset{x\sim a}{=} O(x)$ is  $\exists K\in \mathbb{R}, \exists \eta >0, \forall x\in [a-\eta, a+\eta], |f(x)|\leqslant K|x|$.
- And the definition of $f(x) \underset{x\sim a}{=} o(x)$ is $\frac{f(x)}{x} \underset{x\rightarrow a}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

So for example :

- if we take $a=0$, $f(x)=O(x^2) \Rightarrow f(x) = o(x)$, but the inverse is false, taking for example $f(x)=x^{3/2}$
- but if we take $a=+\infty$, $f(x) = O(x^2)$ does not imply $f(x) = o(x)$ : for example you can take $f(x)=x^2$ : $x^2 = O(x^2)$ but we clearly don't have $x^2 = o(x)$. Conversly $f(x) = o(x) \Rightarrow f(x)=O(x^2)$.